# How do take an input from a webcamera using c program?

Tags: c

I was wondering if you take an input from the camera using c program. 
I use Turbo C, windows xp. I just know the basics of c program, it would be helpful you could describe how one could do this. Thanks in advance. If any clarifications please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Trying to use Turbo C will be too much of an ask for such type of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Window's AVICAP:

- link to the DLL AVICAP32.DLL
- call capCreateCaptureWindow
- send messages to it using SendMessage()

Take a look here:

> http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/multimedia/video/article.php/c1601